# Spawn Control in Capture The Flag

Tags: babo-violent

How exactly does spawn control work? Specifically in Babo Violent CTF matches ?
Sometimes my team leaves holes within our defense leaving to a landslide loss.
I am not looking for something difficult just a simple way to tell team members where to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The guiding principle in spawn control is that **you respawn in the location furthest from the enemy - so your players need to coordinate their locations to force the enemy into spawn points that are bad for them**.  There is a brief little guide [here](http://www.rndlabs.ca/main/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=56:guide-02&catid=25:the-project&Itemid=60), and more [here](http://www.rndlabs.ca/main/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63:guide-03&catid=25:the-project&Itemid=60).

The relevant snippet:

```
All the maps have spawns scattered throughout the map, if the map is 
symmetrical so will the spawns...

A good example would be on the map CTF - Crazy. Lets say it is a 
3 v 3 capture the flag round. Currently, the red team has one player 
on the far top left of the map, one on the top right of the map, and 
one bottom right of the map. 

You had died earlier trying to kill one of them, now you re spawn. 
The game will calculate exactly where the enemy is and that will 
determine where you will spawn. 

Now since one is top left, one top right, and one bottom right, 
you will spawn bottom left. The enemy basically controls three 
corners of the map, the furthest point would be the remaining corner, 
bottom left.
```